# You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs, observable

Say I have the following function references:

```
const externalRequests = (params) => Rx.Observable.zip(
  externalApi1(params),
  externalApi2(params)
)
```

and

```
const internalDB = (params) => Rx.Observable.fromPromise(getStuffFromDB(params)
```

externalRequests returns something of the shape:

```
{ _isScalar: false,
  source: 
   { _isScalar: false,
     source: { _isScalar: false, array: [Object], scheduler: undefined },
     operator: { project: [Object] } },
  operator: undefined }
```

and can be `.subscribe`'d to.

`internalDB`, when `.then`'d directly returns the right data from the database, and when wrapped in `Rx.Observable.fromPromise` as above, returns something of the shape:

```
{ _p: 
   { handle: 115,
     type: 'promise',
     className: 'Object',
     constructorFunction: { ref: 122 },
     protoObject: { ref: 123 },
     prototypeObject: { ref: 1 },
     status: 'pending',
     promiseValue: { ref: 1 },
     properties: [],
     internalProperties: [ [Object], [Object] ],
     text: '#<Promise>' },
  _s: {} }
```

, which, when `.subscribe`'d directly returns something like so:

```
{ isStopped: false,
  observer: 
   { isStopped: false,
     _onNext: [Function: val],
     _onError: [Function: val],
     _onCompleted: [Function: val] },
  m: 
   { isDisposed: false,
     current: { isDisposed: false, current: null } } }
```

Say I now want to flatten all of this into a single stream: so I write something like:

```
Rx.Observable.zip(externalRequests, internalDB).mergeAll().subsribe(() => console.log('potato'))
```

And receive an exception of the form:
`You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.`

To summarize: What is the correct way for me to cast my promise as an Observable, and how do I merge/flatten multiple observables as above?

Comment: My guess is that the problem is in `internalDB` which is a method returning an Observable. It's not an Observable itself so `zip()` can't subscribe to a method. Anyway if you don't provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve it's hard to tell...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @martin mentioned you give functions to the `zip` operator, not observables.

You need to call those functions with the needed `params` for your code to work.

Also, I don't think you need the `mergeAll` call, as the result of `internalDB` and `externalRequests` calls are only observables, not higher order observables (observables containing observables)

```
Rx.Observable
  //    ▼ you need to call the functions in order to get their observables
  .zip(externalRequests(params), internalDB(params))
  .subscribe(() => console.log('potato'))
```

Answer (score 2):

my mistake to import file like this...

```js
import {loginEpic} from "./Epic";
```

and 
i just correct this like...

```js
import loginEpic from "./Epic";
```

Answer (score 1):

usually it's because you imported zip from 'rxjs/operators'

you should import zip from 'rxjs/observable'